# VisualState not working for visibility of a layout

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

In universal Apps(MVVM architecture) my visual state code is not working for the visibility of a layout(with progressbar). Please advise me where I went wrong.

And I followed this [Link](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/handling-visualstate-in-universal-apps-with-behavior-sdk-and-mvvm/)

The VisualState in XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Carrot_Windows.CarrotLoginPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Carrot_Windows"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
DataContext="{Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Progress_layout">
        <VisualState x:Name="BaseState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressGrid">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                    
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="ProgressState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressGrid">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>         
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentState}" 
                                  ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="BaseState">
        <core:GoToStateAction StateName="BaseState" />
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentState}" 
                                  ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="ProgressState">
        <core:GoToStateAction StateName="ProgressState" />
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The Master Layout

```
 <Grid x:Name="Grid_Master" Background="White">

   // THE LAYOUT ON WHICH VISUAL STATE APPLIED
  <Grid x:Name="ProgressGrid" Background="Black" Opacity=".7" Grid.RowSpan="5"    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Canvas.ZIndex="1" >
        <ProgressRing Height="90" Width="90" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True" />
    </Grid>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" >
        <Border  Background="LightGray" Width="520" Height="300" >
            <Grid>
               //Do something
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>

 </Grid>
```

The C# code on VIEWMODEL:

```
 private enum ViewModelState
    {
        BaseState,
        ProgressState
    }

    private string currentState;
    public string CurrentState
    {
        get { return currentState; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref currentState, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentState");
        }
    }

    private void LoginButtonClicked()
    {
        CurrentState = ViewModelState.ProgressState.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I think there is an issue in Value="ProgressGrid">
        <core:GoToStateAction StateName="ProgressGrid" />
is it not called ProgressState?

Comment: @juan Pablo Garcio Coello yeah thank u, but  the visual state 'BaseState' is also not triggered.

Comment: Where in XAML did you add the VisualState and behaviors, below <Grid> ?

Comment: And how did you set the DataContext, can you show that?

Comment: I have added the visual state below the page. I have added some code in my question above(The DataContext ). please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the Visual States to work you need to add below Grid not below Page also place the interaction below the Grid.

Do not worry if it should be on page (that sounds logic), it will work.

And now the following code works:

I have set the CurrentState like the following:

```
 private string currentState;
    public string CurrentState
    {
        get { return currentState; }
        set
        {
            currentState = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I do not know why you use ref.

And to test the state I added:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentState = CurrentState == "BaseState" ? "ProgressState" : "BaseState";
    }
```

(I remove the z-index to be able to click the button)

Now the initialization:

Until the page is not loaded the states is not 'changing' so you need to make the first change to set the basestate:

```
 private async void Initialize()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        CurrentState = "ProgressState";
        CurrentState = "BaseState";
    }
```

So summarizing all of this might be more interesting binding IsActive but might be you need to make a bigger state logic.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. I have already tried both ways by adding to the Grid_Master and  ProgressGrid(layout for which visual state is applied).

Comment: I will create a test project, let me check 5 min

Comment: I have made a test with standard INotifyPropertyChanged take a look to the answer edition

Comment: what about the property did you change the ref to the usual?, does the event arrive to the CurrentState property in your case?

Comment: Yeah,I changed the ref to usual, and the event is hitting both set and get of the property.

Comment: I know it is absurd but could you add a TextBlock with that binding to know if it changes? because if it works I do not know but if dont please add RaisePropertyChanged before I get crazy

Comment: yeah,In the same viewmodel have some other bindings thats working perfectlty, I have tested this with raisepropertychanged too.

Comment: Check the new last part of the answer